# Python. Сортировка выбором

Tags: python, сортировка, сортировка-выбором

```
array = [2, 3, 1, 4, 6, 5, 9, 8, 7] 
 
for i in range(len(array)): # проходим по всему массиву 
    idx_min = i # сохраняем индекс предположительно минимального элемента 
    for j in range(i, len(array)): #  
        if array[j] < array[idx_min]: 
            idx_min = j 
    if i != idx_min: # если индекс не совпадает с минимальным, меняем 
        array[i], array[idx_min] = array[idx_min], array[i] 
         
print(array)
```

Посчитайте количество сравнений, которые производятся в алгоритме выбором из примера.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Код:
...

```
cou = 0 
for i in range(len(array)): # проходим по всему массиву 
    idx_min = i # сохраняем индекс предположительно минимального элемента 
    for j in range(i, len(array)): #  
        if array[j] < array[idx_min]: 
            idx_min = j 
        cou += 1
    if i != idx_min: # если индекс не совпадает с минимальным, меняем 
        array[i], array[idx_min] = array[idx_min], array[i] 
    cou += 1

print('Compares: ', cou)
```

Comment: IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level.                                                        line 14 print(f'Compares: {cou}')

Comment: print('Compares: ', cou) Ааааа так Вы пробелы-то выровняйте

Comment: print('Compares: ', cou)
                            ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: Вы один пробел перед print удалите - уровни не выровнены

Comment: Получается 54 - это не правильный ответ.

Comment: Вам же надо количество сравнений? Ну и посмотрите где они увеличиваются? После операций сравнения. А сколько их тут по Вашему?

Comment: Большое спасибо!